# Unable to get authentication object in context on Refresh action in Adaptive card in Teams Bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We've implemented a Teams Bot with link unfurling functionality. When a link is pasted, a card displaying basic information is generated. We've incorporated a refresh feature in the card schema JSON to present a user-specific view after refreshing the card.
While refreshing the card, we want retrieve authentication information from the Bot context for use in subsequent processes.

Authentication information is available in the context under
**`context.activity.value.authentication.token`** when event handler for unfurling is called which is `handleTeamsAppBasedLinkQuery` and we are able to get the token from context at the time of link unfurling.

However, the challenge arises when attempting to obtain this token during the card refresh or when an action is performed on the refreshed card. In the `onInvokeActivity()` or `onAdaptiveCardInvoke()` event handlers, the value of context.activity.value.authentication is undefined, and the token is not accessible in the context.

Is there a way to get authentication/ token information inside `onInvokeActivity()` or other event handler which is triggered when the invoke happens for refreshing the card?

Comment: Tracking this issue from here-https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/9924